# If inside loop not working as expected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list than contain objects and I want to render each one in a component in a react component, but I need to render only 1 element of each "category"
For example

```
[
{
    "message": null,
    "user": "bob",
    "channel_name": "whatsapp",
    "created_at": "2020-09-22T15:08:48.602Z"
},
{
    "message": "Texto y archivo\r\n\r\n",
    "user": "bob",
    "channel_name": "whatsapp",
    "created_at": "2020-09-22T15:08:46.786Z"
},
{
    "message": "Probar si cada correo genera 2 jsons\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "user": "bob",
    "channel_name": "whatsapp",
    "created_at": "2020-09-22T15:01:27.140Z"
}
```

]

I want my component ChatStram to only render one and only one component with the channel_name "whatsapp", I`m trying to achieve this with a reference list in the ChatStream component and adding each username to the list (channelsRendered), then check if it exists in the reference list if it doesn't exist, then create a component and add it to the list, if it exists mark null. This function is passed to the son component.

The problem is that it always returns all the components despite they are on the reference list or not.

This is the father component

```
import moment from 'moment';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ChatBubbleStream from '../chatComponents/ChatBubbleStream';



     export default function ChatStream({state}){

         let channelsRendered = []

function pushToChannelRendered(nameChannel){
    channelsRendered.push(nameChannel)
    console.log(channelsRendered)
    console.log(channelsRendered.includes(nameChannel))
}

return (
    <div class="overFlowY">
        
        {state.map((thread) => ( 
           channelsRendered.includes(thread.channel_name) ? 
           null 
           : 
           <ChatBubbleStream
            message= {thread.message}
            channel = {thread.channel_name}
            fecha= {moment(thread.created_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}
            messages=  {state.filter(channel => channel.channel_name == thread.channel_name).length}
            pushToChannelRendered={pushToChannelRendered}
            /> 
                    
        ))}        
    </div>
)
}
```

This is the son component

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

 export default function ChatBubbleStream({ channel, reporter, nombre, medio, 
 fecha,  pushToChannelRendered}){


useEffect(() => {
    pushToChannelRendered(channel)
}, []);



return (
    <div class="row">
       Return anything
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Can you copy a sample of namesOfServer?

Comment: names.includes("oscar") should be names.includes(name) I think

Comment: Can you try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? There doesn't appear to be enough code here to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-proskuriakova-oick0?file=/src/App.js:0-703)

It is hard to tell exactly what you want to do but this should help you.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Fake API call
const threeSeconds = 3000;
const newNames = ["Paul Hogan", "Brad Pit", "Billy Madison"];
function loadUsers() {
  return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(newNames), threeSeconds));
}

export default function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState(["Billy Madison", "Happy Gilmore"]);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadUsers()
      .then((newNames) =>
        setNames((prev) => {
          const combined = [...prev, ...newNames];
          const unique = new Set(combined);
          const list = [...unique];
          return list;
        })
      )
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(names)}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to make it two steps.

1. make an array contains non-repeated names

```js
// if namesServer is an array of string
const uniqueNames = [...new Set(namesServer)]
```

2. use `map` to convert it to an array of `<ChatBubbleStream />`

```js
uniqueNames.map(name => (
  <ChatBubbleStream name={name} names={uniqueNames} />
))
```